# Dateadd without using function

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, math

We keep our dates in the DWH in int format.
I would like to do some simple Dateadd calculations (adding and subtract months from a date) without having to convert to date and convert back to int.

I have been able to reach something closing to working using 2 methods:
1. Using Modulo and Absolute functions:

```
DECLARE @EffectiveDate INT = 20121003, 
        @Diff          INT = -12 

SELECT @EffectiveDate + ( Abs(@Diff) / @diff ) * ( Abs(@Diff) + mnt ) / 12 * 
                        10000 + ( 
              Abs(@Diff) / @diff ) * ( ( Abs(@Diff) + mnt - 1 )%12 - mnt + 1 ) * 
       100 
FROM   (SELECT @EffectiveDate / 100%100 Mnt)T
```

2.By calculating the year in months, adding/subtracting the required months and dividing by 12:

```
DECLARE @EffectiveDate INT = 20121003, 
        @Diff          INT = -12 

SELECT ( yr * 12 + mnt + @Diff ) / 12 * 10000 + 
       ( yr * 12 + mnt + @Diff )%12 * 100 + 1 
FROM   (SELECT @EffectiveDate / 100%100 Mnt, 
               @EffectiveDate / 10000   Yr)T
```

In both cases I come up with the same problem, December is represented incorrectly as 0 and effects the year outcome as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without converting to date you will have problems with leap years for adding or reducing days  ;).

Comment: I'm not interested in the exact date, just the month & year, so a leap year has no consequences for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong:

```
SELECT  ( yr * 12 + mnt + @Diff - 1) / 12 * 10000 + 
       (( yr * 12 + mnt + @Diff - 1) % 12 + 1) * 100 + 1 
FROM   (SELECT @EffectiveDate / 100%100 Mnt, 
               @EffectiveDate / 10000   Yr)T
```

Of course everything would be much easier if your store dates in DATEs :)